# Stop eventPropagation after jQuery trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the situation. There is button and there is hidden div. After user clicks the button, hidden div appears and in the same time I'm adding event listener on body using `on()` to check if user clicked out of this hidden div. After that div should be hidden again and click event detached.

Everything works fine but only when user clicks the button. If I trigger click using trigger() function then `on()` function is called immediately and hidden div is not appearing.

Here is the code:

```js
$('button').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('div').toggleClass('active');

   if($('div').hasClass('active')){
     $('body').on('click.div', function(e){
       console.log('body clicked')
       if(! $(e.target).closest('div').length){
         $('div').removeClass('active');
         $('body').off('.div');
       }

     });

   }else{
     $('body').off('.div');
   }
});

$('input').click(function(){
  $('button').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
div{
  display: none;
}

div.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div>This is hidden</div>
<input type="button" value="Trigger">
```

I found also solution how to solve this problem, but I still dont know why using `trigger()` and `stopPropagation()` does not work.

Here is fixed code with using `setTimeout()`:

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('div').toggleClass('active');

  if ($('div').hasClass('active')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('body').on('click.div', function(e) {
        console.log('body clicked')
        if (!$(e.target).closest('div').length) {
          $('div').removeClass('active');
          $('body').off('.div');
        }

      });
    }, 0);

  } else {
    $('body').off('.div');
  }
});

$('input').click(function() {
  $('button').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div>This is hidden</div>
<input type="button" value="Trigger">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the click on the `input` that you responded to by calling `trigger` propagates to `body`, and so it gets handled by the `body` handler you add. That is, the click that triggers this event handler:

```
$('input').click(function(){
  $('button').trigger('click');
});
```

...gets processed; and then of course you're sending another one later.

To fix it, just stop that click from propagating:

```
$('input').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('button').trigger('click');
});
```

```js
$('button').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('div').toggleClass('active');

   if($('div').hasClass('active')){
     $('body').on('click.div', function(e){
       console.log('body clicked')
       if(! $(e.target).closest('div').length){
         $('div').removeClass('active');
         $('body').off('.div');
       }

     });

   }else{
     $('body').off('.div');
   }
});

$('input').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('button').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
div{
  display: none;
}

div.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div>This is hidden</div>
<input type="button" value="Trigger">
```

The reason your `setTimeout` version worked is that you were delaying hooking up your `body` click handler until *after* the click on the `input` had reached `body`, so it didn't get triggered by the click on the `input`.

Comment: Yup thats the reason. For a while I've been thinking that maybe I need `stopPropagation` in function with trigger, and then let go. Thanks!